# how to convert japanese string into widechar from api MultiByteToWideChar in mfc application

Tags: c++, mfc

I convert Japanese string into widechar but output string comes garbage like??????
my code snippet 
input string

```
 CString strp ="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\新しいテキスト ドキュメント\オィデーオ.mp4"      

    LPCWSTR pchData1 = NULL;
    pchData1 = (LPCWSTR)strp.GetBuffer(strp.GetLength());
    TCHAR * japUni; 
    int lens = strp.GetLength();
    lens = lens*2;
    japUni= new TCHAR[lens+2];
    memset(japUni,0x00,(lens+2));
    LPCSTR pszNonUnicode;                                       
    USES_CONVERSION;
    pszNonUnicode = W2A( strp.LockBuffer( ) );
    strp.UnlockBuffer( );
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_UTF8,0,pszNonUnicode,lens+2,japUni,lens+2);
    strp.Empty();
    strp = japUni;          
    if(japUni)
    {
        delete []japUni;
        japUni = NULL;
    }
```

> output string    C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\?V?????e?L?X?g ?h?L???????g\?I?B?f?[?I.mp4

please suggest what I am doing wrong in the above code.....

Comment: rename the file to english version maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the input string as you've shown it is an impossible situation:

```
CString strp ="C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\新しいテキスト ドキュメント\オィデーオ.mp4"
```

The first glaring problem is that you've not escaped your backslashes, so the path string is malformed.

The second is more serious. The fact that this compiles at all suggests that you're compiling for a multi-byte character set (*i.e.*, non-Unicode). If you were compiling for Unicode, `CString` would be defined as `CStringW`, which cannot be initialized with a narrow string literal. So `CString` must actually be `CStringA`.

Alarm bells are going off now. That's why you needed the `LPCWSTR` casts. You are telling the compiler to pretend that a narrow string buffer is actually a wide string buffer. Oops. Same problem when you try to convert `strp` (a narrow string) with the `W2A` macro. It is not a wide string, so it cannot be converted *from* one. Try to avoid playing the `TCHAR` game when you're converting between string types. It is better to be explicit. If it is a wide string, use `WCHAR`; if it is a narrow string, use `CHAR`.

Anyway, I'm guessing that your input string is in the Japanese code page, 932. If that's the case, you should be able to convert it directly to a wide string. I can't test this on my system, I don't have that code page active.

```
CStringA strJapanese = "C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\新しいテキスト ドキュメント\\オィデーオ.mp4";
CStringW strUnicode;
const int cchBuffer = strJapanese.GetLength() * 2;  // reserve plenty of extra space
if (MultiByteToWideChar(932,
                        MB_PRECOMPOSED,
                        strJapanese,
                        strJapanese.GetLength(),
                        strUnicode.GetBufferSetLength(cchBuffer),
                        cchBuffer) == 0)
{
   const DWORD dwErrCode = GetLastError();
   // Failed; handle error.
   // ...
}
strUnicode.ReleaseBuffer(-1);
```

The other possibility is that your string is UTF-8 already, in which case you'd pass `CP_UTF8` as the first parameter and `0` as the second. Otherwise the code is the same.

Comment: `CString` offers conversion constructors, that allow you to construct a `CStringW` from an MBCS string, and a `CStringA` from a wide character string. The first line of code you quote compiles just fine in a Unicode build.

Comment: Ugh, really? It didn't compile for me in my little MFC test project. Is it something you have to enable with a preprocessor define, @IInspectable? I don't remember having run into this before. Implicit conversion is evil in general, but that seems like a particularly cruel trick to play on unsuspecting programmers...

Comment: You don't have to enable this feature. It works out of the box. There are 2 [CStringT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cws1zdt8.aspx) constructors, taking a `const XCHAR*` and a `const YCHAR*`. Those represent the native and respective other character encoding, respectively.

Comment: @IInspectable Ah, I see what the problem is. The default project template defines `_ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS`, which means that a simple initialization from a literal, as shown here, will fail. (There is also a `_CSTRING_DISABLE_NARROW_WIDE_CONVERSION` macro, but as you said, that must be explicitly defined. It is not by default). Not sure what to make of the original code. If the implicit conversion ctors are being called, it is even more nonsensical than I imagined. Probably shouldn't even have tried to answer this one.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `_ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS` preprocessor symbol. If it is defined by default today, then that's good. I believe this hasn't always been the case in previous versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: It is there by default at least since VS 2008. I'm still using VS 2010 day to day. I think it happened when they merged the ATL and MFC implementations of CString, but I'm not sure. I don't think MFC had the implicit conversions to begin with, so it was only an ATL thing.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case of Japan though...

If you use vs2003 or earlier version, compiler's default is mbcs(Shift-JIS(old Japanese code)) in Japanese.
If you use vs2005 or later version, compiler's default is wbcs(Unicode) in Japanese. [/D _UNICODE]

MBCS: UTF-8, S-Jis(old Japanese code on Windows)
 WBCS: Unicode(UTF-16)

In case of the former:

```
CString szShiftJis = "blahblah esktop\新しいテキスト ドキュメント\オィデ・・・";
char bufUTF8[MAX_PATH];
char bufShiftJis[MAX_PATH];

WCHAR bufUnicode[MAX_PATH];

// (1)mbcs→Unicode
int iLenUnicode = MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, szShiftJis, strlen(szShiftJis)+1, NULL, 0);
if (iLenUnicode <= sizeof(bufUnicode)/sizeof(bufUnicode[0]))
{
    MultiByteToWideChar(932, 0, szShiftJis, strlen(szShiftJis)+1, bufUnicode, MAX_PATH);

    // (2)Unicode→mbcs(UTF-8)
    int iLenUtf8 = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bufUnicode, iLenUnicode, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (iLenUtf8 <= sizeof(bufUTF8))
    {
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bufUnicode, iLenUnicode, bufUTF8, sizeof(bufUTF8), NULL, NULL);
    }
}
```

In case of the later:

(1) is unnecessary.

Comment: using your code part input file name is オィデーオ and output file name comes オィチE�Eオ which is not correct please suggest for this problem thanks

Comment: using above code input string C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\新しいテキスト ドキュメント\オィデーオ.mp4 output comes C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\譁ｰ縺励＞繝・く繧ｹ繝・繝峨く繝･繝｡繝ｳ繝・繧ｪ繧｣繝・・繧ｪ.mp4 which is not correct please suggest for .....correct conversion

Comment: on english os  int iLenUtf8 = WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bufUnicode, iLenUnicode, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
    if (iLenUtf8 <= sizeof(bufUTF8))
    {
        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_UTF8, 0, bufUnicode, iLenUnicode, bufUTF8, sizeof(bufUTF8), NULL, NULL);
    }above line of code  work fine for japanese string but in japanese os not working....

Comment: Do you use an editor for multi-codeset?

「新しいテキスト ドキュメント\オィデーオ.mp4」
It seems that byte code for this sentence is as follows.
[shift-jis]
90 56 82 B5 82 A2 83 65 83 4C 83 58 83 67 20 83 68 83 4C 83 85 83 81 83 93 83 67 5C 83 49 83 42 83 66 81 5B 83 49 2E 6D 70 34
[utf-8]
E6 96 B0 E3 81 97 E3 81 84 E3 83 86 E3 82 AD E3 82 B9 E3 83 88 20 E3 83 89 E3 82 AD E3 83 A5 E3 83 A1 E3 83 B3 E3 83 88 5C E3 82 AA E3 82 A3 E3 83 87 E3 83 BC E3 82 AA 2E 6D 70 34
In the case of lower part of code, "譁ｰ縺励…" is displayed, if you use s-jis's editor.

Comment: problem solved CT2A ascii(ctring,CP_UTF8);
     TRACE(_T("UTF8: %S\n"),ascii.m_psz);

Comment: problem solved CT2A ascii(cstring,CP_UTF8);
     TRACE(_T("UTF8: %S\n"),ascii.m_psz);  cstring = =ascii.m_psz; then we use cstring in the function which take char ptr thats why problem occure.and now finaly I correct the mistake using  ascii.m_psz in function ascii.m_psz is a char ptr.

Comment: If you have 'atlconv.h', you should use it.  ftp://osu-tulsa.okstate.edu/Delen/VS.NET/CD1/Program%20Files/Microsoft%20Visual%20Studio%20.NET%202003/Vc7/atlmfc/include/atlconv.h
That macro calls the same functions.